# Regex parsing issue with different types of strings

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a scenario where I have two possible types of strings of data; one numeric, and one text.  What I need to do is to parse the numeric strings, but not the text strings.  As it currently stands, I have this test project, which feels close to what I want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = "8,000 4,567 (12.9) 3,567.98 -19.9 £12,234.5 ($123.12)";
    string test2 = "Fire phasers, Mr. Sulu";
    string test3 = "Phasers on setting 3, Mr. Chekov";

    DisplaRegexSplit(test);
    DisplaRegexSplit(test2);
    DisplaRegexSplit(test3);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void DisplaRegexSplit(string test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test);

    string[] splitStr = Regex.Split(test, @"(\d)*(\d+)*(\d*\,*\d*\.*\d+)+");

    foreach(string s in splitStr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

However, it's still splitting on commas, and of course, it isn't catering for the various special numeric chatacters.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here; either with, or without Regex?

Comment: Try [`Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%29*%7c%5cd%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f&i=8%2c000+4%2c567+%2812.9%29+3%2c567.98+-19.9+%c2%a312%2c234.5+%28%24123.12%29%0d%0aFire+phasers%2c+Mr.+Sulu). Probably, even [`\d[\d.,]*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%5b%5cd.%2c%5d*&i=8%2c000+4%2c567+%2812.9%29+3%2c567.98+-19.9+%c2%a312%2c234.5+%28%24123.12%29%0d%0aFire+phasers%2c+Mr.+Sulu) will work for you, too.

Comment: Thankyou.  with a bit of playing, I almost managed to get that to work  [\(\d\-\$\£]*\d[\-\d\.\,\)]* ; however, when I introduce a number into the string value, it treats it as a numeric value

Comment: So, the results for string3 should be empty? See https://ideone.com/4Wt0vI. Note that an optional currency symbol can be matched with `\p{Sc}?`.

Comment: @qwerty Because the string could be *I've payed €100 for my new shoes*... It would be difficult and very contextual to comprehend what is what. You could try to put a `(?!.*\p{L})` to remove all the strings that have at least a letter... But I'm not sure it would be a good idea.

Comment: I ended up taking the approach that any text ([a-z]) in the string was just excluding and then used the Regex above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more like what you want:

```
private static void DisplaRegexSplit(string test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test);

    var collection = Regex.Matches(test, @"(\(?-?\p{Sc}?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)*\)?)");

    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} Matches", collection.Count);

    foreach(Match match in collection)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}
```

This isn't perfect as it could incorrectly match `(-$30` without a closing bracket, it will match the patterns you have provided :)